# Api Token Authentication - through parameters or headers?

Tags: api, http, authentication

I wrote some API. It requires an API token.
I only access this API through backend.
Should I receive the API token through headers only, or is it ok to receive it from query string parameters?
Are there differences security-wise?

Edit: forgot to mention, of course I use SSL

Comment: Sending credentials over query parameters can expose them. Headers are more secure

Answer (score 0):

All the Authorization is in Headers only headers are more secure 
In query parameter these are expose for the public

for eg. if you send in Like a query it will be public to all

**Don't do this Ever**

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5051/v1/user/verifytoken?token=bearer-xdrRxfdfdfdf
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need a refresher on the differences between cookies and tokens to assist you in finding your answer.

The purpose of cookies is to bring state to what is inherently a stateless protocol which is http, the http protocol has no concept of state and it's only by introducing these cookies or tiny bits of data on requests that identify us to the server.

Cookies are included on all http requests by default, **they manifest themselves as a property on the header of any request**. A server can choose to place information on a users cookie that identifies them uniquely to that particular server.

So if they were logging into a website I were making I could stick some information into that cookie that says this is user13794 and on any follow up request they would have a cookie 13794 that says this is the same user coming back, it's another request from the same person.

Cookies are automatically included on all requests and very importantly, are unique to each domain, such as Google.com versus eBay.com. A cookie you have that is tied to google.com is not and cannot be shared by default with ebay.com, that is how we get some level of security on all of our requests. So if I logged on to google.com and then went to hacker.com, the hacker.com website could not lift my cookie from Google and hijack my session.

SO cookies cannot be sent to different domains, that is something that exists for security purposes so you cannot easily hijack peoples sessions.

Opposed to cookies are the ideas of tokens, this was introduced as a convention, to use tokens in place of cookies where cookies stop being useful.

There is nothing done automatically for us with tokens, **we have to manually include a header with our token which might be a string of letters and numbers and we might include it on a specific header so we have to manually wire up our tokens at all times.**

The benefits of tokens is that we can send them to any domain that we wish, so if I am on google.com and I want to make an authenticated request to an entirely different domain, I can do so by using a token.

I would make my request to that other domain, include my particular token and boom! I am authenticated on that other domain.

So that's my long winded way of saying, like with cookies, tokens are manually wired up through headers only, not query parameters.